# Ubuntu on HP Compaq NX 6120

Tags: sound, drivers, touchpad, vga

How do I install Ubuntu on an HP Compaq NX 6120? What drivers do I need (audio, VGA , touchpad, wireless LAN)?

Can I use AutoCAD 2009 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

You can install ubuntu by downloading an ISO image from [ubuntu homepage](http://www.ubuntu.com). Image can be put on usb disk with programs like unetbootin and then you can install (or just try) ubuntu directly from usb.

You don't need any drivers for ubuntu except some proprietary drivers (like vga and wlan) which you can install with "Additional Drivers" program that you can run on freshly installed ubuntu system.

AutoCAD and any other software that is made for windows can't be installed on ubuntu or any other linux distribution, but there is a program (Wine) that emulates windows system and you can install some windows software with it. But this kind of software usage can be really buggy and sometimes it can't work.
Other option is to install Windows in virtual machine in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have download ubuntu in my hard drive. Now i want to install it . HOW ???

Comment: Download and install unetbootin from this site: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Then open it and select ubuntu iso image that you downloaded and then write it to usb disk.

When that is finished, boot from usb disk and follow ubuntu installation instructions.